# issue while using extend & yield for Master Layout

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

[image]

[image]@yield('header') not working dont know why please help

Directory structure
view 
Folder:master->Files masterPage.blade.php,header.blade.php
Folder:userControl-> Files dashboard.balde.php

Master page code:

```
<div class="wrapper">   
  @yield('header') **not working**
      <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      @yield('content')  **working**
      <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
      <footer class="main-footer">

      </footer>
```

Header.blade.php

```
  @extends('master.masterPage')
    @section('header')

    <header class="main-header">          
       some code
    </header>
    @stop
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to @endsection. This is how I yield sections using your example.

This is how you should define your header section.

```
@section('header')
<header class="main-header">          
   some code
</header>
@endsection
```

This is how you should reference them yield this section.  Include the location of your partial file this way.

```
@include('folder.partial')
@yield('header')
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

issue was because of using two yield 
instead i need to use `@include` in this situation

Comment: Isn't that what I highlighted in my answer?